# uploading file not working in codeigniter 3 error: you did not select any file

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller, codeigniter-3

i have created the root directory and set its path, i done the front end as was. the ide is not giving any error but when i proceed it say you did not select any image.

the controller code:

```
class Images extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->data['displayname'] = $this->admin->lastname;
        $this->data['images'] = Image::all();
        $this->data['btn'] = 'Save';
        $this->data['content'] = 'admin/images/index';
        $this->load->view('layouts/admin', $this->data);

    }
    public function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        //$config['max_size']      = 100;
        //$config['max_width']     = 1024;
        //$config['max_height']    = 768;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('images'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
             // echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('index', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }

    }
}
```

the view code:this is the form for choosing the file

```
 <?= form_open('admin/images/do_upload') ?>
            <label><?= form_upload('images[]')?></label>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-image" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ul>

    <div class="line"></div>

<?= form_submit('', 'Submit', 'class="publish-btn"') ?>

<?= form_close()?>
```

Comment: Codeigniter upload library is built for one upload at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after a lot of research and trying lots of codes and i solved my issue
here's the full thing 
the controller code:

```
 public function create($id)
    {
        $config ['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
        $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config ['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $package = Package::find($id);

        $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES ['images'] ['name']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {

            $_FILES ['images'] ['name'] = $files ['images'] ['name'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['images'] ['type'] = $files ['images'] ['type'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['images'] ['tmp_name'] = $files ['images'] ['tmp_name'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['images'] ['error'] = $files ['images'] ['error'] [$i];
            $_FILES ['images'] ['size'] = $files ['images'] ['size'] [$i];
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('images')){
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $package->create_images(array('image_location' => $file_name));
            }
        }

        redirect('admin/packages/');
    }
}
```

the view code:

```
<div class="container">
    <?= form_open_multipart('admin/images/create/' . $this->uri->segment(4)) ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 publish">
            <h4>Image Gallery</h4>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <ul>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>



                    <div class="input-group control-group after-add-image">


                        <label><input type="file" name="images[]"></label>

                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success add-image" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </ul>

                <div class="line"></div>

            <?= form_submit('', 'Submit', 'class="publish-btn"') ?>

            <?= form_close()?>
            <div class="clear-all"></div>
            <!-- Copy Fields-These are the fields which we get through jquery and then add after the above input,-->
            <div class="copy-field" style="display: none">
                <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
                    <label><label><input type="file" name="images[]"></label></label>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-delete"></i> Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    //here first get the contents of the div with name class copy-fields and add it to after "after-add-more" div class.
                    $(".add-image").click(function(){
                        var html = $(".copy-field").html();
                        $(".after-add-image").after(html);
                    });
//here it will remove the current value of the remove button which has been pressed
                    $("body").on("click",".delete",function(){
                        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

its getting all the images dynamically, uploading them to the directory and then stores the path to the database 
 done!

[the image for front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su5Td.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?= form_open_multipart('admin/images/do_upload') ?>
```

Use the above code instead of

```
<?= form_open('admin/images/do_upload') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i added the multipart to my form which created an issue of invalid path which i solved by initializing the library after adding

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

after this line of loading the library.

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

first load the library then initialize. 
but still the problem of an selection is not solved 
i tried a couple of other  codes too.

Answer (score 0):

In file uploading case you should use

```
<?php form_open_multipart('admin/images/do_upload') ?>
```

Not this

```
<?php  form_open('admin/images/do_upload') ?>
```

Comment: it is not uploading the picture

Comment: says the upload path does not appears to be valid

Comment: problem solved for uploading the file. the problem is in the view file not the controller. the form is not responding to the function because i was using this:

<label><?= form_upload('images[]')?></label> 
an array of files because i am going to submit multiple images.

it worked when i used:

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /> a single file.
but i am require to submit multiple images at the same time. what should i do to overcome this issue, because i have already tried array mechanism and its not working.

Comment: add this line 
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" />

Comment: i did this but it is not working 
 i am adding the input fields dynamically like its not an abstract number no of fields ,, it can be 3, 4 or 1